# Login to TFS using external URL

Tags: login, windows-home-server, authentication, webserver, team-foundation-server

I've installed Team Foundation Server 2010 on my WHS (in 'Basic' configuration, no Sharepoint or Server Proxy or Build Automation) and have enabled port forwarding on my router. If I use **http:// localhost:8080/tfs/web** or **http:// foobar:8080/tfs/web** I can log in using *username*.

However, attempting to log in via **http:// foobar.homeserver.com:8080/tfs/web** will not let me log in. After a couple of attempts with different variations on the username, I get a 403 error, with access denied. I've tried *foobar.homeserver.com\username*, *foobar\username* and just *username*, but to no avail.

Any ideas? I've checked that there are no IP restrictions within ISS.

Thanks

Comment: "It will not let me log in" - in what way? Are you getting an error page before or after you try to log in?

Comment: You're right, I should have been clearer (I'll update the question). I get 403 after trying to login a couple of times, as though it's an incorrect username or password - but if I use the internal URLs, I can log in with _username_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who was interested, I hadn't configured my user to use Web Access specifically, as I was able to log in with the Administrator account I had installed TFS with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to configure alternate access mappings in Sharepoint. Doing this should be relatively the same in all editions of Sharepoint.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208(office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but the server does not have Sharepoint installed, only TFS basic.